# Is it possible to crop an image <img> in css without a parent container or setting it as background?

Tags: html, css, image

Is there a way to crop an image (img tag) with css, without php, javascript, using a parent element or setting the image as a background image? As an example, lets say I have an image of 400 x 400 px, contained in an html document like so:

```
<img src="400x400.jpg" />
```

Is there a way to crop this image purely in css (without distorting the image)? I'm asking this because it would be the more semantic way of cropping an image, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely! This is the wonderful but often misunderstood `clip` property.

```
clip:rect(110px, 160px, 170px, 60px); /* Random example */
```

It works all the way back to IE4. You can find out more information with [this fantastic tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/).

Comment: Downside is that the element you want to crop needs to be set to position:absolute. Which kind of limits its usefulness when used on an img-tag, which I want to be flowing with the document content. I could use a parent container to assign space for it, but that would defeat the purpose of this solution (as it requires an extra unsemantic element, which I'm trying to avoid). Good suggestion though, thanks.

Comment: this is a best of possible scenarios answer ... you're not going to find the exact thing u want, because it doesn't exist. in terms of processing and overhead, this is the cleanest, fastest, and most maintainable solution you're going to find.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible. Too bad. Was hoping someone knew a way to do this.

Comment: yep. and thanks to whomever voted this down, clearly you understand how the voting system is intended to work.

Comment: The absolute position should be no problem. You just have to wrap the `img` into an element that doesn't have static positioning. Absolute position is _relative_ to the first parent element without static positioning. The naming _absolute_ is a little confusing. Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Thanks for the interesting answer.

Comment: i think he understands that, he just wanted to do this with no additional markup whatsoever, including any non-semantic HTML. and shame on you for using W3schools as a reference! avoid doing that else far more scathing returns will befall you...http://w3fools.com/

Comment: That's right. I was hoping it would be possible, but alas. All they had to do is make cropping possible on an element without the absolute positioning..